# iteration through column values in python w.r.t index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyjiN.png)

where columns are true ,i want column name,
where more than one columns are true: columns name separated with /

blank cells are empty string

Required output:

Natural gas: Dark cloud
Copper : Bearish Harami
Nickel : bearish belthold
Aluminium : inverted hammer/bearish harami

Answer (score 0):

You can do this unsing `pandas.DataFrame.apply()` on `axis=1`.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.nan, True], 'b':[True, np.nan],  'c':[True, np.nan]})

>> df
      a     b     c
0   NaN  True  True
1  True   NaN   NaN

df_ = df.apply(lambda x: ' / '.join(x.dropna().index), axis=1).to_frame()
>>> df_ 
       0
0  b / c
1      a
```

I hope this is what youa re asking for.